# Glut Ring of Spikes

Tags: c++, shapes, freeglut

I am trying to create a ring of 8 spike-plates using freeglut. Every plate should be rotated/tilted by 30 degrees relative to the center ball, and all of them are supposed to be ordered in ring-form. Here is an example:

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```
void Larvitar::drawTail()
{
    // Create tail ball
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor4f(0.2, 0, 1, 1.0);
    GLUquadric *tail;
    tail = gluNewQuadric();
    glTranslatef(0, 0.2, -3.0);
    gluSphere(tail, 1, 100, 30);
    glPopMatrix();

    double xrotate = 30;

    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 45)
    {
        double rnd = ((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX));

        glPushMatrix();
        glColor4f(rnd, 0, rnd, 1.0);
        glRotatef(xrotate, 1, 0, 0); // kippen?
        glRotatef(i, 0, 0, 1);  // Kreisform
        glScalef(1, 0.4, 2);
        glTranslatef(0, -2, -2.1);
        glutSolidCube(1);
        glPopMatrix();
        xrotate -= xrotate;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the plates are in ring form but not each one is tilted by 30 degrees outwards, only the first one is. What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this in a loop without having to create every plate by hand?

Comment: Look at your last line in the `for` loop: `xrotate -= xrotate;` What is the effect of that statement in the first loop iteration, and what happens then in the following iterations?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.

```
    void Larvitar::drawTail() {
    // Create tail ball
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor4f(0.2, 0, 1, 1.0);
    GLUquadric *tail;
    tail = gluNewQuadric();
    glTranslatef(0, 0.2, -3.0);
    gluSphere(tail, 1, 100, 30);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor4f(0.58, 0.655, 0.482, 1.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 45) {
        glPushMatrix();

        glRotatef(i, 0, 0, 1);
        glRotatef(30, 1, 0, 0);
        glScalef(1, 0.5, 2);
        glTranslatef(0, -2, -2.1);
        glutSolidCube(1);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```